# Angular Ui-Router : using only current state in ui-sref and removing parent states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS ui-router in my application for the first time. Say my application have the following structure

```
   home.html      
   --UserProfile.html      
   ----Password.html 
   ------change passowrd.html
   ------reset password.html
```

In password.html , I want to create two links for reset/change password. For this situation, I am writing password.html as below,

```
<a ui-sref="home.profile.password.changepassword>Change Passowrd</a>
<a ui-sref="home.profile.password.resetpassword>Change Passowrd</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Is it correct way of defining states here? I feel bad for seeing a lengthy state definition in the pages. Can i get the parent state automatically and just use

```
<a ui-sref="changepassword>Change Passowrd</a>
```

some how and make it work?

Comment: Yes ~ `".changepassword"`. See examples here http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go_parameters

Comment: @Phil, Thank you:) That worked. Could you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it and close this thread?